# How to use += with a object?

Tags: c#

the code below is working fine (no conpiler error, it's mean code no error)

```
   //....
    public static void CreatePingers(int kt)
    {
        for (int start = 1; start <= kt; start++)
        {
            //class System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
            Ping p = new Ping();
            //This code working fine, But it mean use += for object type?
            p.PingCompleted += Ping_completed();
            pingers.Add(p);
        }
    }

     public static PingCompletedEventHandler Ping_completed()
    {
         PingCompletedEventHandler a = new PingCompletedEventHandler(abc);
         return a;
    }
   //....
```

But my test code doesn't work:

```
   //....
   static void setB()
   {
       Class3 b = new Class3();
       //Error"Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Class2' and 'Class2'
       b.B += a();
   }

   public static Class2 a()
   {
     Class2 b = new Class2();
     return b;
   }
   //....
```

What is diffirent between them?

Comment: See [Events Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa645739.aspx), especially the part about "Hooking up to an event". -- also, `first += second;` is syntactic sugar for `first = first + second;`. You can [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8edha89s.aspx) the `+` operator in your class, if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

because you are not adding an object by `+=`.
you are assigning yet one more eventhandler to the event mechanism.

The thing is that inside an event lies a list of delegate methods to call.
+= adds one more method to this list.
-= would remove a method from the list...

Comment: but you could always overload the "+" and "=" operators, and then += would work for two objects of same or compatible types....

Answer (score 0):

You're doing two completely separate things. This line:

```
p.PingCompleted += Ping_completed();
```

Is attaching the method `Ping_completed` as an event handler for the `PingCompleted` event of object `p`.

Your other line is attempting to just add one `Class2` object to another, which the compiler does not understand, because there is no addition operation defined between the classes.

So, counter-question: what are you intending for this to do?

Comment: You can't simply just declare a class and expect addition to work. The compiler has no hope of figuring that out. However, if you want an event which operates like `PingCompleted `, or delegates, which are similar in many ways, you *can* use the add-assign (+=) and subtract-assign (-=) operators to attach or detach specific methods to the execution of that event/delegate.

Comment: For a basic event overview, check out: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_events.htm as it looks like about as basic of an example as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Event classes override `+` to enable syntax like:

```
p.PingCompleted += Ping_completed();
```

To make this work for your class, simply override the static `+` operator in `Class2`:

```
public class Class2
{
    ...
    public static Class2 operator +(Class2 p1, Class2 p2)
    {
         return whatever the result of adding is...
    }
}
```